# Angular How to Wait for Response using HttpClient

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm using a restful api on my angular application.

```
forgotPassword(mail: string) {
    const apiURL = 'https://myapiendpoint';
    const connect = this.httpClient.post(apiURL, { email: mail },
        { headers: {
             'Content-type': 'application/json',
             responseType: 'text'
            }
    });
        return connect.toPromise();
    }
```

The API gets called with no issues, but I can't get an response back from the server.
The guy that created the API said he can see on his end this:

> message port closed before response was received

any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the part of code where you are subscribing to this request?

Comment: Simply subscribe to the POST request Observable like  this.httpClient.post(apiURL, { email: mail }).subscribe();

Answer (score 0):

please don't use Promises for http requests, this is not reactjs.

use Observables instead

```
forgotPassword(email: string): Observable<any> {
    const httpOptions = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    };

    const queryUrl: string = `'https://myapiendpoint`;

    return this.http
      .post<any>(queryUrl, JSON.stringify(email), httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          return response;
        })
      );
  }
```

then just subscribe from your component:

```
service.forgotPassword(email).subscribe(result => {
 // do something
});
```

Comment: Hey @AlleXyS I tried as you've described but I still get the same error :/ Could this be an error on the API?

Comment: please share your httpinterceptor